# Issue with servers behaving differently on WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, iis-7

We have three servers we run our primary site on. They use Window Server 2008 R2, fully patched / updated, and MySQL 5.5.

The first and second servers work with no issues. However, the third server (which is physically identical to the second server, however the networking is a bit different - the second server uses a Meraki device) has an issue.

We implement a custom WordPress plugin, that uses the getimagesize() function (normally uses @ in front of the function, but I've removed this to try to see the error). I've also disabled the Windows firewall just to cover my bases.

On the third server, when loading the WordPress back end, it stops at the function containing the following code. Logs show no specific error, and the page error is only that the maximum time was exceeded (which is currently 6 minutes to test this issue). php is run via FastCGI on IIS7.

Any insight as to what could cause this would be appreciated!

Here is the loop:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($contentNoReferences);
libxml_use_internal_errors($internalErrors);
$totalImages = 0;

// Gather image data
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img)
{
  $fileName = $img->getAttribute('src');

  $ignoreFileDimensions = true;

  // Exclusion cases... CTAs, charts, infographics, graphs, and diagrams (treat _ as -)
  $checkName = str_replace('_', '-', $fileName);
  if(strpos($checkName, '-CTA-') === false &&
    strpos($checkName, '-CTA.') === false &&
    stripos($checkName, '-chart-') === false &&
    stripos($checkName, '-chart.') === false &&
    stripos($checkName, '-diagram-') === false &&
    stripos($checkName, '-diagram.') === false &&
    stripos($checkName, 'infograph') === false &&
    stripos($checkName, 'graph') === false)
  {
    $ignoreFileDimensions = false;
  }

  $totalImages++;
  $lastSlash = strrpos(str_replace('\\', '/', $fileName), '/');
  $fileName = substr($fileName, $lastSlash + 1, strlen($fileName));

  $fileStats = getimagesize(get_option('siteurl') . '/../images/' . $fileName);

  if($ignoreFileDimensions)
  {
    $fileStats[0] = -1;
    $fileStats[1] = -1;
  }

  if($fileStats)
  {
    $images[] = array('filename' => $fileName, 'type' => $fileStats['mime'],
    'width' => $fileStats[0], 'height' => $fileStats[1],
    'size' => remote_file_size(get_option('siteurl') . '/../images/' . $fileName),
    'class' => $img->getAttribute('class'),
    'title' => $img->getAttribute('title'), 'alt' => $img->getAttribute('alt'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `getimagesize` exists?

Comment: @cwallenpoole thanks for the suggestion. I thought about that as well and have verified that getimagesize is a valid function.

Comment: Can you measure how much time it takes to download the file? (`$fl = sys_get_temp_dir () . '/' . $fileName ; file_put_contents($fl, file_get_contents(get_option('siteurl') . '/../images/' . $fileName);`)

Comment: There's no noticeable delay. Really stumped on this one...

Comment: I've also verified folder permissions on the images directory.

Comment: What if you download it locally and then call `getimagesize` on a local version?

Comment: Same results. Would it matter if they are hosted on a CDN?

Comment: You might want to re-install the GD library for PHP. CDN should not change any of this, but what happens if you query IIS from the machine itself?

Comment: Reinstalling GD didn't help, I'm trying a local query now.

Comment: The local query didn't seem to change anything. I have reinstalled php and the associated libraries, and reset all the folder permissions. I will be trying again tonight. @cwallenpoole Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue.

Our CDN responds quickly and doesn't have the error, but when the files are local there are some ip lookups in between, that each add a delay into the access of the files.

This caused a timeout ultimately.